# Open leanmodal popup by clicking on dynamically generated links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

I am using the jQuery leanmodal plugin (http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/)

I have a PHP page where there are links to update the data using the leanmodal popup:

The following links with different parameters passed to the functions are generated in the main page to show the leanmodal popup.

```
<a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42690');">Edit</a>
<a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42691');">Edit</a>
<a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42692');">Edit</a>
<a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42693');">Edit</a>
```

......

This same page also gets some link generated using ajax call (added into the document using jQuery) which also is like the same link as mentioned above but the leanmodal popup and the function is not getting executed:

```
<a id="42694" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#" onclick="showDataDetails('42694');">Edit</a>
<a id="42695" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#" onclick="showDataDetails('42695');">Edit</a>
<a id="42696" rel="leanModal" name="editdetails" href="#" onclick="showDataDetails('42696');">Edit</a>
```

......

is it related to with the binding of `onclick` event to dynamically created anchor link elements in jQuery.

I want to open leanmodal popup by clicking on dynamically generated links:

```
function showDataDetails(id) { 
....
....
}
```

Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set unique REL attribute for each groups of links to same modal. If you set two same ID for two nodes then selector not be worked correct.

```
function showDataDetails(id) {
  ...
   $("[rel*="+id+"]").leanModal({...});
  ...
}
```

**But i think...**
Code must look like:

for example data table

```
 <table>
 <tbody>
    <tr id='42694'><td data-name="Ron">Ron <a href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42694');">Edit</a></td></tr>
    <tr id='42695'><td data-name="Harry">Harry <a href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42695');">Edit</a></td></tr>
    <tr id='42696'><td data-name="Hermiona">Hermiona <a href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42696');">Edit</a></td></tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

then you can dynamically add same anchor code

```
<a href="#editdetails" onclick="showDataDetails('42695');">Edit</a>
```

your modal window

```
<div rel="leanModal" id="editdetails" class="modal">
   <form>
      This is EDIT modal content
      <input id="idInput" type="hidden" name="id" />
      <input id="nameInput" type="text" name="name" />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

and in function. Before show modal, you must store data from related field to modal form.

```
function showDataDetails(id) {
   // get the value of field
   let nameValue = $('#'+id+' td[data-name]').data('name');

   // put the value to form input in modal window
   $('#nameInput').val(nameValue);
   // put the id in hidden input for backend purpose
   $('#idInput').val(id);

   // show one modal for all fields
   $('#'+id+' a').leanModal();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pretordh/j28r6vko/

Comment: as per the documentation... 
if we want more than one modal window on the same page, simply add the 'rel' attribute to your triggers, and call the function by attribute, like so:

$("a[rel*=leanModal]").leanModal(); 

This is already done on Jquery onload...

Comment: The documentation assumes that the developer understands how IDs and selectors work. Each ID must be unique on page. ID selector return only one node.

If developer simple copy paste source code - he must undertand how it works. And then he must adapt seample code to yours application.

Comment: Thanks for the code above.... I tried it.. its not showing the leanmodal popup even on the static links in the page ( the ones in the table )....

Comment: Sorry, i fix this bug.

Comment: Bug fixed. Please, get responce.